# XUnit Test Case for Azure service bus using ISenderClient.SendAsync()

Tags: azure, moq, asp.net-core-webapi, azureservicebus, xunit.net

I am using IsenderClient interface for sending message to our Azure Service Bus. For that we are writing XUnit test case using Moq. In one of our test case we want to check if we are sending valid message or not. We want to verify the Message[User Property] and Partition key. How can i write it can any one help me?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but are you focusing on a correct `Message` construction or the message sending? The latter is working and doesn't need to be tested. Message construction is your domain and doesn't require mocking of the client.

Comment: Add you sample code here